# Retrieving the Keys by comparing the values in a map

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am trying to print the keys by comparing the values of a map with the given input as string (input is given in the below tried executed sample output).

See the below code I tried code:

```
-module(main).
-compile(export_all).
 get_code_for_words(Sentence) ->
   Words = string:split(Sentence, "\s", all),
   LettersWords = # { "a" => ".- ","b" =>"-... ","c" =>"-.-. ","d" => "-.. ","e" => ". ","f" => "..-. ","g" => "--. ","h" =>".... ","i" =>".. ","j" =>".--- ","k" =>"-.- ","l" =>".-.. ","m" =>"-- ","n" =>"-. ","o" => "--- ","p" =>".--. ","q" =>"--.- ","r" =>".-. ","s" =>"... ","t" =>"- ","u" =>"..- ","v" =>"...- ","w" =>".-- ","x" =>"-..- ","y" =>"-.--","z" =>"--.. "},
   Result = get_codes(Words, LettersWords, _AllCodes=[]),
   io:format("~p~n", [Result]).
            
 get_codes([Word|Words], Map, AllCodes) ->
    NewAllCodes = maps:fold(fun(K,V,Acc) ->
                           %io:format("~p~n",[Acc]),
                           case V =:= Word of
                                true -> [K|Acc];
                                _    -> Acc
                           end
                       end,
                       AllCodes,
                       Map),
            get_codes(Words, Map, NewAllCodes);
        get_codes([], _Map, AllCodes) ->
            lists:reverse(AllCodes).
```

When I executed the code , the output is below:

```
**

9> c(main).                           
    main.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
    {ok,main}
    10> main:get_code_for_words(".... ..").
    []
    ok
```

**

Please suggest me ?

Comment: Thanks 7stud for the expalnation, I tried with your provided example function get_code_for_words(Sentence) does what I am asking for. The function takes a sentence and splits it into words, then it takes each word in turn and it looks through every value in the map to find matches for the word, and if a match is found the key for the matching value is added to an accumulator. Its works properly, but the output is printing.

Please suggest me ?

Comment: None of the values in your map are `"...." ` or  `".." `, so what  would you expect the output to be?

Comment: In the defined Map ("a" => ".-  ","b" =>"-... ",) , I just removed the extra space in the value of Map(And my Map will be ("a" => ".- ","b" =>"-...",). Then the value is compares with the input , I executed and got the required output. Thanks @7Stud.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first reformat your code (with the help of `rebar3_format`):

```
get_code_for_words(Sentence) ->
    Words = string:split(Sentence, "\s", all),
    LettersWords =
        #{"a" => ".- ",
          "b" => "-... ",
          "c" => "-.-. ",
          "d" => "-.. ",
          "e" => ". ",
          "f" => "..-. ",
          "g" => "--. ",
          "h" => ".... ",
          "i" => ".. ",
          "j" => ".--- ",
          "k" => "-.- ",
          "l" => ".-.. ",
          "m" => "-- ",
          "n" => "-. ",
          "o" => "--- ",
          "p" => ".--. ",
          "q" => "--.- ",
          "r" => ".-. ",
          "s" => "... ",
          "t" => "- ",
          "u" => "..- ",
          "v" => "...- ",
          "w" => ".-- ",
          "x" => "-..- ",
          "y" => "-.--",
          "z" => "--.. "},
    Result = get_codes(Words, LettersWords, _AllCodes = []),
    io:format("~p~n", [Result]).

get_codes([Word | Words], Map, AllCodes) ->
    NewAllCodes =
        maps:fold(fun(K, V, Acc) ->
                     case V =:= Word of
                         true -> [K | Acc];
                         _ -> Acc
                     end
                  end,
                  AllCodes,
                  Map),
    get_codes(Words, Map, NewAllCodes);
get_codes([], _Map, AllCodes) ->
    lists:reverse(AllCodes).
```

Now, let's isolate the map so I don't have to copy it around all the time and, since this doesn't look like an escript, let's just remove the call to `io:format/2` for the result…

```
letters_to_words() ->
        #{"a" => ".- ",
…
          "z" => "--.. "}.

get_code_for_words(Sentence) ->
    Words = string:split(Sentence, "\s", all),
    get_codes(Words, letters_to_words(), _AllCodes = []).
```

Now, let's talk about `get_codes/3`…
Since that function is using the map above, I'll assume that you when you say `Word`, you actually mean `Character` (since otherwise you'll have to go char-by-char, but this function goes word-by-word)…

Let's first use pattern-matching instead of a boolean `case` statement…

```
get_codes([Word | Words], Map, AllCodes) ->
    NewAllCodes =
        maps:fold(fun(K, V, Acc) ->
                     case V of
                         Word -> [K | Acc];
                         _ -> Acc
                     end
                  end,
                  AllCodes,
                  Map),
    get_codes(Words, Map, NewAllCodes);
get_codes([], _Map, AllCodes) ->
    lists:reverse(AllCodes).
```

Now, I'll assume that you expect this to happen…

```
8> a_module:get_code_for_words(".- -.-.").
["a","c"]
```

But, instead, you get…

```
8> a_module:get_code_for_words(".- -.-.").
[]
```

And, to understand why that happens, let's see what's the result of `string:split/3` in your case…

```
9> string:split(".- -.-.", "\s", all).    
[".-","-.-."]
```

As you can see, those strings have no trailing spaces, like the keys on your map. So… replacing your map with the following one should fix your issue…

```
letters_to_words() ->
        #{"a" => ".-",
          "b" => "-...",
          "c" => "-.-.",
          "d" => "-..",
          "e" => ".",
          "f" => "..-.",
          "g" => "--.",
          "h" => "....",
          "i" => "..",
          "j" => ".---",
          "k" => "-.-",
          "l" => ".-..",
          "m" => "--",
          "n" => "-.",
          "o" => "---",
          "p" => ".--.",
          "q" => "--.-",
          "r" => ".-.",
          "s" => "...",
          "t" => "-",
          "u" => "..-",
          "v" => "...-",
          "w" => ".--",
          "x" => "-..-",
          "y" => "-.--",
          "z" => "--.."}.
```

Comment: Thank You @Brujo Benavides, for this "As you can see, those strings have no trailing spaces, like the keys on your map. So… replacing your map with the following one should fix your issue…" really its solved my problem and its executing perfectly.